# Let, $M$ and $N$ be $R$ modules. Then, $M \otimes_{R} N \simeq N \otimes_{R} M$

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, tensor-products

Define, $\phi(\alpha_1 (m_1 \otimes n_1) + \dots \alpha_k(m_k \otimes n_k )) = \alpha_1 (n_1 \otimes m_1) + \dots \alpha_k(n_k \otimes m_k )$; such that, $\alpha_i \in R$. Then, $\phi$ is a map from $M \otimes_{R} N$ to $N \otimes_{R} M$. Assuming the map $\phi$ is well defined then we have a $R$ module hom from $M \otimes_{R} N$ to $N \otimes_{R} N$. I'm trying to finish this proof, but now I have a few problems, I don't know how to prove that the map $\phi$ is well defined, and I don't know how to prove that $\phi$ is an injection, it is obvious that $\phi$ is a surjection. Any help with some how showing that $\phi$ is well defined?

I know one can solve this problem using the universal properties of the tensor product, but I wanted to demonstrate the isomorphism directly using $\phi$.

Comment: The map that induces the bilinear map $M \times N \to N \otimes_R M,\, (m,n) \mapsto n \otimes m$ using the universal property is $\phi$! Therefore, $\phi$ is well-defined by this reason.

Comment: @azif00, I see so maybe the homework question was badly worded.

Comment: To show it is well defined, just show that it is bilinear and maps $x\cdot r\otimes y$ to the same value as it does for $x\otimes r\cdot y$. To show it is bijective, just define an inverse map by swapping factors again, and this is well-defined by the same reasoning.